# mysqli counts how to divide these two counts and echo result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am wanting to divide these two counts then echo the result of the division in the table ['final_count']. Can someone please help me fix where I'm going wrong...

```
<table class='table table-bordered'>
<?php

    $connection = mysqli_connect("******", "******", "******", "******");
    if (!$connection) {
        die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $Date = '2019-03-11';
    $Win = 'Win';

$testsql="SELECT 
count(IF(betDate = '$Date', 1, 0)) AS bet_count,
count(IF(betDate = '$Date' AND result ='$Win', 1, 0)) AS win_count
 FROM bets";

$testresult = mysqli_query($connection, $testsql);

while ($testrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($testresult))
{ 
    echo "<tr>";
echo "<td class='text-center'>".$testrow['final_count'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

mysqli_close($connection);
?>
</table>
```

Comment: And `count(win_count)` counts what?

Comment: Counts the rows in the table where, the column date is = $date and column result = to $win ('win' string) but the win_count is not counting where as bet_count is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display it:

```
{ 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='text-center'>".($testrow['win_count']/$testrow['bet_count']). "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
```

though I would also improve you SQL query:

```
$testsql="
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS bet_count,
  SUM(IF(result = $Win, 1, 0)) AS win_count,
FROM test WHERE betDate = $Date
";
```

---

And on a further side note - if you want to learn working with MySQL & PHP, I'd highly encourage you to learn [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) instead of mysqli. Even though it appears to be more complicated - it will teach you the basics of object-oriented programming and some good habits related to the work with MySQL, such as parameters (question marks in example below).

For example your query in PDO would be

```
$sql = "
SELECT
  COUNT(*) AS bet_count,
  SUM(IF(result = ?, 1, 0)) AS win_count,
FROM test WHERE betDate = ?
";
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->execute([$Win, $Date]);
$results = $sth->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think there is a slight issue with the division of the calculation, there are three rows in the table where the date = $date, and one of them where result = $win , yet the result is still 1 when it should be 3

Comment: Still, calculation is incorrect when I add GROUP BY

Comment: If i change the echo to echo `<td class='text-center'>".$testrow['win_count'] . "</td>";` the result is 3, when it should be 2 as out of 3 rows only two of them have the column Win

Comment: You should use SUM instead of count. COUNT will count you all values, regardless what they are (be it 0, 1, or anything else). I updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks for your help, highly appreciated :). Great day to you.

Comment: Would love having answer marked as useful, hehehe ;) And welcome to the Stack Overflow!